# How can I "bridge" VNC traffic from two clients connected to a C# proxy-type server?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, proxy, reverse-proxy

I'm looking to develop an asynchronous C# TCP server which can act as a proxy between two client VNC connections, passing data between the two transparently.

I've already got some asynchronous client-server code set up where I can effectively communicate messages between the server & any connected clients, now I need a way to host a kind of proxy for VNC traffic.

```
Client A--------------Server--------------Client B
 VNC traffic sent -> relayed through server -> VNC traffic received
```

And then any response from client B to simply flow back to the server, then transitively to client A.

If any more information is required for a proper answer, please do let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Huh?  VNC clients can't talk to each other, clients talk to servers.  So we assume that A and B are servers respectively, and you're using a proxy to provide NAT traversal.  There are a number of solutions already available, if you google "VNC NAT traversal" or "VNC proxy", some of which are open source which you can therefore study and learn from.

Comment: Can you tell me more about the answer you selected and how you have implemented it?

Comment: I was incorrect in my answer, which is most likely why I received a -1 vote.  The link I posted allows the bridging of TCP traffic, but it must be custom traffic, so unless you're implementing the VNC protocol yourself, the class is of no assistance.  I never got a real answer on this question, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this answered on Server Fault...the key is to launch "socat" from your application and use it to "link" the connections together.

See: https://serverfault.com/questions/254855/socat-connect-connect-proxy-two-inbound-tcp-connections-to-expose-a-firewalled

For more information.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you already can receive data on the server that is sent from the client - you just write exactly what you read from one client back out to the other connected client.

It seems like you've already done the hard work, and I'm confused as to what part you're not understanding on how to finish it up.

Comment: Sorry I wrote this question in the middle of the night without thinking about it.  My question was totally wrong. Please review the edited question.